# Multiple PKI tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now, we have three PKI-related tags: [certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates), [public-key-infrastructure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key-infrastructure) and [certificate-authority](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate-authority). There is considerable overlap between these three tags. Existing questions which use them seem to have used the tags somewhat at random. Could we simply merge them all together ? I suggest [public-key-infrastructure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key-infrastructure) as the common name (the others becoming synonyms to that one).

Note that there are sub-tags for specific kinds of PKI, namely [x.509](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x.509) and [pgp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgp). I do not suggest to merge those (however, a lot of PKI-related questions could be tagged [x.509](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x.509) as well).

(Also, "certificate authority" should be "certification authority".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While these tags do indeed have a lot in common, and there is indeed overlap, I think they focus on different aspects.

Often someone would want to ask specifically about attributes of [certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificates), or applicative use and storage, for e.g. asymmetric encryption (sans PKI). 
Or some questions would be specifically about how to secure or restrict a [certificate-authority](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate-authority), without going into the wider PKI-implementation details. 
Or they're looking at the user management end of [public-key-infrastructure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key-infrastructure).

So yeah, they're definitely close and similar, and often you'd be using more than one (perhaps even as an incomplete subset of another), but I don't think they are identical, or close enough to merge.

Btw, regarding "certificate authority" vs. "certification authority" - both Google and Bing return twice as many hits for the first than the second. Wikipedia has both registered on the same article, but has "[certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Certification_authority&redirect=no)" as the canonical link. so, not quite conclusive, in either direction - but I would not be against a synonym from the 2nd to the 1st.